# Sqlite Where ? condition not get data from HTML selected option

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, filter, sqlalchemy

I have one select option on Html page. When I select one of them I want query to filter report according to selected data.

but I is not matching with WHERE knit_status = ?

I have codes as below.

Html side :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/knitreports" method='POST'
            <select name="rep_knit_status" >
                <option value="Null">Status.. </option>
                <option value="Ready">Ready</option>
                <option value="Exported">Exported</option>
            </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" target="_blank">Report</button></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@app.route('/knitreports', methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
def knitreports():
if request.method == 'POST':
    rep_knit_status = request.form.get('rep_knit_status')
    knitreports = db.session.query("SELECT knit_status,knit_boxnr,knit_ord_no,knit_style_no,knit_st,knit_var_No,knit_XS,knit_S,knit_M,knit_L,knit_XL,knit_XXL from knitting WHERE knit_status =? 
    db.session.execute(knitreports,(rep_knit_status,))
return render_template('knitreport.html',knitreports=knitreports)
```

Where knit_status = ? (I couldn't match with select from HTML form.

When I input  Where knit_status = 'Ready' it is working. but I have two choice  'Ready' or 'Exported'

Answer (score 0):

In `knitreports = db.session.query...` line you have to say from in uppercase. Change from from to FROM also put ") at the end and you have to say what knit_status is:

```
knitreports = db.session.query("SELECT knit_status,knit_boxnr,knit_ord_no,knit_style_no,knit_st,knit_var_No,knit_XS,knit_S,knit_M,knit_L,knit_XL,knit_XXL FROM knitting WHERE knit_status =?", (my_knit_status,))
```